# Возвращение статуса ошибки Spring RESTful сервисом

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, исключения, rest

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, найти решение.

У меня есть простейший RestController, который принимает данные в POST-запросе, обрабатывает их и отсылает ответ клиентскому приложению (в виде коллекции).
Как вернуть http-ответ с кодами ошибок 404, 403 и т.д., если, например, после обработки возвращается пустая коллекция?

Я имею   в виду, что, если в методе контроллера во время обработки данных у меня произошло исключение, можно ли вернуть ответ, содержащий статус ошибки? Так, чтобы код ошибки указывался мной? Может быть, кто-нибудь подскажет, где найти пример или литературу по этому поводу?

Мне казалось, что может помочь что-то связанное с @ExceptionHandler, но не могу найти по нему объяснений. Вот книжка Manning бы очень помогла, если бы существовала по этому вопросу...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Мне казалось, что может помочь что-то связанное с @ExceptionHandler, но не могу найти по нему объяснений.

Неясно, как вы искали, потому что первая же ссылка по запросу "spring exceptionhandler" выдает: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Спасибо большое! Почему-то эту статью я благополучно упустила при поисках