# Изменение полей ошибки

Tags: java, spring

Если при запросе что-то пошло не так, то `RestController` выкинет `json` такого вида:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1510417124782,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException",
    "message": "ApplicationRepository#save(Application) failed and no fallback available.",
    "path": "/application"
}
```

Объект какого класса был сериализован для этого ? Могу я как-то влиять на этот объект и заносить в рантайме статус и сообщение этого объекта ?

Comment: связанный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/396832/ , но лучше бы кто-то нормальный ответ написал

Comment: @zRrr сам спросил - сам ответил)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Покурил туториалы и доки и вот, что я понял:***

По умолчанию тот `json`, что мы видим является объектом класса `DefaultErrorAttributes`.

Задать свой обработчик `rest` - ошибок не так уж и сложно. Для этого нужно знать о следующих вещах:

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` - класс, который собственно и занимается перехватом исключений и решает, что необходимо вернуть пользователю. У него много методов с названием по типу `handle` + название исключения.

`ControllerAdvice` - аннотация, которая дает "советы" группе контроллеров. По сути это некий хук для них. По умолчанию аннотация действует на все контролллеры, но в ее параметрах есть опции для указания конкретных групп.

`ExceptionHandler` - аннотация для ловли определенных ошибок.

Соответственно, для того, чтобы поймать некоторое исключение, обработать его и отдать что-то пользователю необходимо создать класс с аннотацией `ControllerAdvice` и унаследовать его от `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. После чего переопределить нужное исключение.

Примерно вот так:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAsyncRequestTimeoutException(AsyncRequestTimeoutException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest webRequest) {
        return super.handleAsyncRequestTimeoutException(ex, headers, status, webRequest);
    }
}
```

В случае, если мы хотим обработать свое исключение или какое-то другое специфическое исключение не из класса `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` можно использовать конструкцию такого вида:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(HystrixRuntimeException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHystrixRuntimeException(HystrixRuntimeException e) {
        HttpTypicalError error = getHttpTypicalError(e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorAnswer(error.getMessage()),
                HttpStatus.valueOf(error.getStatus()));
    }
}
```